# Prevent popup.html of Chrome from being closed by iframe action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I embedded an iframe in my popup.html of my extension. Inside this iframe the use has to submit by clicking on a button. This opens a new tab which causes my popup.html to be closed.

How can I force the popup.html to remain active?

This is necessary as the iframe processes with more information.

My popup.html: http://pastebin.com/QftvfQ8c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not force a popup to remain open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means I cannot embed an iframe that processes data in several steps / on several pages?

Comment: You might try loading a local extension page that loads the several steps in an iframe. Something like the Owly Socialbar would probably work: http://ow.ly/socialbar

Comment: Could you provide me with some more details?

As for now I do not have any idea what to do with socialbar.

Regards

Comment: The basics of it would be to create a HTML page with is only a few hundred pixels tall and include the iframe below it with the several pages as needed.